# The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: javascript, html

When I click to the HTML document to open it in browser the fllowing message appears: 
"The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with index.html garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
I don't know how can insert my code here

Answer (score 17):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Just below `<head>`

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` or this `<meta charset="UTF-8" >` worked for me

Comment: Adding <meta charset="utf-8"/> solved my issue in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

> Here is the HTML5 basic structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
     </head>
  <body>
    <!--The content of the document......-->
  </body>
</html>
```

> **Note :** `UTF-8` is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible Unicode code point.

Here is more details about [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` or this `<meta charset="UTF-8" >` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you use Atom or sublime, you can install the the very useful package called Emmet. All you have to do is enter `!` , then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, Emmet will automatically complete the basic structure of HTML5 for you. In this case problems like something missing or a typo will not appear, and one less thing for you to worry about.

For sublime, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and install package.
For Atom, here is the GitHub address: [Emmet support for Atom](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom)

Comment: This is not a solution related to this question. For `SublimeText-3` no need to use any external plugins for HTML `Auto Complete`. Just `Save` the file first as `.html` or `.php` or other extensions, Then write `html` to the file and use `Ctrl`+<`Tab`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite follow you. I'm taking baby steps learning Web development, and I guess there's a whole new world waiting for me. I tried your method on my SublimeText-3 but it didn't work. What does `Ctrl`+<`Tab` mean? I mean the middle part. My system is Windows 10. Thank you.

Comment: And I didn't mean the auto complete in my answer, i meant the basic structure like your answer to this question show. Of course we don't have to use any external plugins for auto complete for SublimeText-3. And thank you anyway.

Comment: Opps! Its actually `Ctrl`+`Tab`